# How do i request user input for the matlab code provided?

Tags: matlab

```
I = imread('image.jpg');
imshow(I);
K = imadjust(I,[0.35 0.45],[]);
figure
imshow(K)
imwrite(K,'image.jpg')
```

I want a pop up dialog box for user to input the value of [0.35 0.45]. How do I modify the coding provided to prompt for user input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [`inputdlg`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputdlg.html):

```
I = imread('cameraman.tif');
imshow(I);
% prompts for the two inputs
prompt = {'Enter LOW contrast limit:','Enter HIGH contrast limit:'};
% title of the dialog box
dlg_title = 'Input';
% number of input lines available for each variable
num_lines = 1;
% default answer for each input
defaultans = {'0','1'};
% generate the dialog box and wait for answer
answer = inputdlg(prompt,dlg_title,num_lines,defaultans);
% convert string answers into doubles
lo_in = str2double(answer{1});
hi_in = str2double(answer{2});
% apply on image
K = imadjust(I,[lo_in hi_in],[]);
figure
imshow(K)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much. It worked like how i expected. Could you also help me with another problem? I will post a new question later